# How to replace specific dictionary value based on key using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I tried below code but somehow it is not working.

```
 employeesList.ForEach(x => x.ToDictionary(y => y.Key, W => W.Key == "DeptID" ? (W.Value == "1" ? "ECE" : "EEE") : W.Value));
```

I have a key called `DeptID` in `Dictionary`. It has values like `1` or `2`.
So, my requirement is if `DeptID` value is `1` then I need to replace `1` with `ECE` else replace with `EEE`.

I tried above code but not working.

Did I made any mistake?

**Update 1:**

I have a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>()` with few items. I want to modify values of `DeptID` key.

My requirement can be achieved using below code.

```
        foreach (var a in employeesList)
        {
           if (a.ContainsKey("DeptID")) { 
              if (a.ContainsValue("1")) { a["DeptID"] = "ECE"; }
              else if (a.ContainsValue("2")) { a["DeptID"] = "ECE"; } 
                }
            }
```

I want to get same result with very fewer lines of code.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Code using ToDictionary not working.

Comment: LINQ is for querying, not modifying anything. `ForEach` isn't a LINQ method, and doesn't return anything. This code creates temporary dictionaries and then discards them. What are you trying to do? What dictionary are you trying to modify?

Comment: What is `employeesList`? A list of `Employee` objects? Or Grouped employees? What do you want to produce?`employeesList.Select(x => x.ToDictionary(y => y.Key, W => W.Key == "DeptID" ? (W.Value == "1" ? "ECE" : "EEE") : W.Value));` would produces an `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,....>>`, is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do with LINQ is better left to imperative code, as others have mentioned in comments that LINQ queries data but is not for mutating it.

Furthermore, your original LINQ statement creates temporary dictionaries and discards them.

However, if you still want to go with a LINQ-based solution here's a way it can be done.

```
employeesList.Where(employee => employee.ContainsKey("DeptID") && (employee.ContainsValue("1") || employee.ContainsValue("2"))
    .Select(employee => 
    {
        employee["DeptID"] = employee.ContainsValue("1") ? "ECE" : "EEE";
        return employee; 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions but I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
employeesList.ForEach(x => x["DeptID"] = x["DeptID"] == "1" ? "ECE" : "EEE");
```

See [JSFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W6vNru)

However I personally do not think it is a good style to mutate the data using LINQ and other approaches should be considered. Depending on your design you might wish to consider using objects for your employees rather than dictionaries of key/value pairs.

Comment: Nope. That's not what the OP is doing.